# How to print values of array using print_r php?

Tags: php, html

I have an array of values stored in variable "do"
It's something like this but not exactly

```
<html>
  <input type='text' name='do' id='do'>
  <input type='text' name='do' id='do'>
  <input type='text' name='do' id='do'>
  <input type='text' name='do' id='do'>
  <input type='text' name='do' id='do'>
</html>
```

and I print it all with the use of [print_r] then it gives a result

```
<?php
print_r($_POST['do']);

//and i try this also
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
  echo $key . ' : ' . htmlentities($val,ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";?>   
}


[do=1&do=2&do=3]
```

how could I modify or just print the values like this:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: what you are trying to do with the same names??

Comment: Pls post what's stored in $_POST['do']

Answer (score 1):

Do not assign multiple elements the same ID (that's why it's out) but change the name in order to send an array of elements as POST

```
<input type='text' name='do[]'>
<input type='text' name='do[]'>
<input type='text' name='do[]'>
<input type='text' name='do[]'>
<input type='text' name='do[]'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
  echo $val;
```

^^ would do. However you cannot edit like $val=something. To change value, use $POST[$key]=something;

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
```

Answer (score 0):

this won't work properly because you're overriding the same variable with different values and end up having one variable with the last value assigned.

Change this to

```
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
```

So you can loop through it like this:

```
foreach($_POST['do'] as $key => $val)
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP overwrites the values with same *plain* names when parsing POST data into `$_POST`.

You may instead write the following form code:

```
<html>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
<input type='text' name='do[]' id='do'>
</html>
```

Now, `$_POST['do']` is the array containing five `do` strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done this way:

```
<input type="text" name="do[]" id="do_1" />
<input type="text" name="do[]" id="do_2" />
<input type="text" name="do[]" id="do_3" />
<input type="text" name="do[]" id="do_4" />
<input type="text" name="do[]" id="do_5" />
```

Then on POSTing, just look inside $_POST['do'] to get an array.

Edit: note that the apostrophes have been switched to quotes, the IDs have been made unique, and each tag has been self-closed. In general it will not validate otherwise.